# useEffect always works

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

This useEffect is always rendering a page, how can i optimize it?

const [problemsData, setProblemsData] = useState([])

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:3001/problems").then((resp) => {
        setProblemsData(resp.data)
    })
}, [problemsData])
```

if i make this

```
useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("http://localhost:3001/problems").then((resp) => {
            setProblemsData(resp.data)
        })
    }, [])
```

It doesn't rerender my application without updating the brawser page

Comment: The 2nd example looks good, can you clarify the issue?

Comment: When i make a new post, my application doesn't render again, it means that it doesn't give me my new element in my FRont, but after refreshing all application, i can see this

Comment: That’s a different issue. This logic is responsible for initializing the state in the initial render. You’ll need to share how you handle when a user adds a new post. You’ll need to update state with the new post.

Comment: const onSubmit = (values) => {
         axios.post("http://localhost:3001/problems", values).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          }).catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
          })
    }

Comment: I dont' understand why it doesn't work, because i do the same as in the official docs...

Comment: That doesn’t update the state, why are you expecting it to?

Comment: Can you link the example (“official docs”) you’re referring to?

Comment: https://github.com/machadop1407/FullStack-Course/tree/Episode4/client I make the same with this guy, but in my realisation

Comment: all src is on Client

Comment: https://github.com/Shapa291/site this's is my project, i get data in App.js and post it in folder User/UserInterface

Comment: The first app you linked has separate pages for create and home, so every time you go home it will re-render and make the api call again (getting the new post made in the create page).

Comment: So as i understand, i need to make callback function in App.js and give with props to my component where i make Post?

Comment: Ok, as yous say, in this case it must work with useEffect(,[]), but id doesn't

Comment: Right - you need to pass the function as a prop - see my answer for more detail. I'm not sure what you're asking in your latest comment.

Comment: It not helps me, because I need some data from database,  such time createdAt and Id

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd solution is the correct way to initialize your state, the issue you're having is that you aren't updating state when you create a new problem. Updating the state with the new problem will cause the components to re-render with the updated problems.

1. You should use an environment variable for your endpoint, as it will change when you deploy.
2. You can pass a a create function down from `App` (to the children that need it) that will update the state, causing the children to re-render. Below I'm assuming that the response is in the right format, if it's not - you could transform it to the right format or do another GET request (not ideal).

```
function App() {
  ...
  const createNewProblem = (values) => {
    axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API}/problems`)
      .then(newProblem => {
        setProblemsData([...problemsData, newProblem]);
      });
  };
  ...
}
```

Comment: I need to take extra data in database such as time created at  and id

Comment: Why not return that in the POST response?

Comment: You can also mock the data on the front end by manually adding it to the object using `Date`. As I mentioned you can also just fetch them all again, but we usually want to reduce the amount of api calls made (performance, stability etc).

Comment: Did you figure it out?